# Firebase cloud functions make a POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase database and I want a cloud function(trigger) to communicate with a REST node.js webservice I have.

The trigger is already created, but now I want that the cloud function to call a external webservice I have in a hosted machine.

I imported jQuery. But it says that *$.post is not a function*. I thought it would be because the slim version was installed somehow(not the case). Then I tried to do it directly in JavaScript using XMLHttpRequest, which the function also says

> ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
>       at /user_code/index.js:91:19
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)

Do you have any clue how to make a *POST* request on firebase cloud functions?

Comment: I've been trying to do the same thing with same error. have also tried with npm packages: request, request-promise, superagent. Using these it always errors with getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Comment: just found out getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND were happening because i was testing from a non-paid account.  request & request-promise work if on paid account - on blaze plan

Comment: Yup i was in the same situation, apparently the free version only allows outbound calls to google services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be on a paid firebase plan (possibly Blaze) in order to POST to an external website.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42775841/6480950

Can use npm modules request & request promise.

Basic Test: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43645498/6480950

Comment: Thank you very much :) this was it in the documentation could be a note because of that only after checking the billing price i understood :D thank you

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Cloud Functions is a Node.js environment. But jQuery is a client-side javascript library. There are a few server-side jQuery builds (Cheerio, nodeQuery), see here: [Can I use jQuery with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js)

But I would . . .

try using node module xmlhttprequest. It let's you write raw requests the way you would in client-side JavaScript. You'll need that dependency in your package.json file ie:

```
"dependencies": {
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0"
}
```

Then in your function:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.addEventListener('load', doSomethingWithDataFromResponse);
request.open("GET","http://urlToMyServer");  
request.send();

function doSomethingWithDataFromResponse() {
  var data = this.responseText;
  //etc.
}
```

For a POST something like:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = "word=foo"; //or stringify some JSON
request.addEventListener('load', doSomethingWithDataFromResponse);
request.open("POST","http://urlToMyServer"); 
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); // or application/json etc.
request.send(params);
```

That's how I've been doing requests from a node server to other third-party servers lately. I haven't had a chance to try it with Firebase yet, but all documentation seems to indicate that it should work.

Comment: Even tho in the localhost i am ablle to use and import JQuery to node.js, inside google cloud functions i was not able to import them, it was always saying the package was not defined, request package was the one that worked properly with my solution