# Is it possible calling other API in Cloud functions using firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to make some push alarm on iOS

When user set Alarm on specific time, and Server sends Weather Data by calling Weather API (ex OpenweatherMap) that time.

is it possible by using cloud functions in Firebase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with the request module.

See [Use firebase cloud function to send POST request to non-google server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415759/use-firebase-cloud-function-to-send-post-request-to-non-google-server) where you will find:

```
// import the module
var request = require('request');

// make the request
request('put your external url here', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        //here put what you want to do with the request
    }
})
```

Note that you will have to activate a paid plan, because the free plan (Spark plan) only allows "outbound network requests only to Google-owned services"

Note also that you have to install the request package before being able to call it as shown above.

Comment: awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec Do you know how you could get a JWT token to include in an external request? I need to call another server, but it requires JWT token for authentication (Along with a custom claim in the JWT)